# find total time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all I am trying to calculate total work time for staff , when staff enter Start time and End time, I need to display total work time in JS

I am trying to do that in below code and don't work ..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $time1 = $("#start");
  var $time2 = $("#end");
  var $diff = $("#totalTime");

  function updateHours() {

    var dtStart = new Date("10/16/2017" + $time1.val());
    var dtEnd = new Date("10/16/2017" + $time2.val());
    var dtEndafterlunch = new Date("10/16/2017" + $time5.val());


    var diff = (dtEnd - dtStart);

    $diff.val(diff / 1000);
  }
  $time1.add($time2).on("change, keyup", function() {
    if ($time1.val() && $time2.val()) {
      updateHours()
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="time" id="start" name="logintime" />
<input type="time" id="end" name="logouttime" />

<input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: What didn't work? Are you getting any errors? Are you getting the wrong result? What is the result you expect? What is some sample input?

Comment: Learn to debug: `console.log("10/16/2017" + $time1.val(), new Date("10/16/2017" + $time1.val()))` Look at your console for errors.

Comment: no things appear or show in total time ! i enter start and end work no result show !!

Comment: $time5 is not defined

Comment: `$time5.val()` - where is `$time5` defined?

Comment: remove comma between event names in `on` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've altered your snippet, it is not common to use $ in variables within JS, although there are some situations where it is useful see the comment section below.

The difference in time is now shown in seconds.

Take a look at the following code, if you have questions please leave a comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $time1 = $("#start");
  var $time2 = $("#end");
  var $diff = $("#totalTime");

  function updateHours() {

    var dtStart = new Date("10/16/2017 " + $time1.val());
    var dtEnd = new Date("10/16/2017 " + $time2.val());
    var dtEndafterlunch = new Date("10/16/2017 " + (dtEnd - dtStart));


    var difference = (dtEnd - dtStart)  / 1000;

    $diff.val(difference);
  }
  $time1.add($time2).on("change keyup", function() {
    if ($time1.val() && $time2.val()) {
      updateHours()
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="time" id="start" name="logintime" />
<input type="time" id="end" name="logouttime" />

<input id="totalTime" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but it is not common to define your variables `time1`, `time2` etc. like `$time1`, `$time2`, etc. Also it is better to use `jQuery` instead of `$` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Hi @Frank Groot It's work in Second how to convert in HH:MM?

Comment: ah I see - in that case, still common (more so with app developers I've noticed - or maybe just app devs I've met).. and for the second part you fix doing `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and issue solved

Comment: @MohammedJuma To convert to minutes divide `difference` with 60. To convert to HH:MM format you need to create another function.

Comment: can you help me with this function ? @FrankGroot

Comment: @FrankGroot actually having a `$time` variable is a common pattern. Maybe not widely used but definitely shows up. It a variation of Hungarian notation - it signifies that the variable holds a jQuery object. It's very useful when wrapping an HTML element in jQuery, so you get a `$this = $(this)` in an event handler or `$el = $(el)` in a loop so you can use jQuery methods. The notation helps when you see `$panel.text(newValue)` - you'd immediately that changes the text content of an HTML element instead of having to read the context to get that.

Comment: @vlaz, never thought about such thing thanks for the clarification. Definitely something to consider in future projects.

Answer (score 2):

Please add a space between date and time like below

`var dtStart = new Date("10/16/2017 " + $time1.val());`